# Why is dataset[, uniqueN(x)] in data.table not returning the correct count of unique values within variables in RStudio?

Tags: r

I am working with a dataset which has 379561 instances and 75 variables. I want to calculate Summary Statistics(Mean, Standard Deviation, #outliers,range) for this data. The variables are of the type (numeric, integer and categorical). Because its a comparatively large data set, my conventional code is taking too much time. So I decided to go with data.table package in R. Now my dataset has some binary coded (0 1 variables) variables which I want to be treated as categorical. For this I am writing a function which counts the unique entries in each variable and if the #unique entries is < 10, I want to treat this particular variable as Categorical. I have written the following code. But it returns the count as 1 for all variables. I have attached[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c61Cx.png) my code.

Thank you for help and also if possible, suggest me an alternative to data.table.

Comment: Your code uses uniqueN(x) as an index. There is no standard R function with that name.   Is that a typo?

Comment: Please post your code in text form (preferably formatted as a code block using stackoverflow's formatting buttons). Also, please provide sample data so we can copy your code into R and run it on our own computers. The goal is to allow us to reproduce the exact problem you are having. In general, `data.table` is a great solution for summarizing and counting large datasets.